# Convertion faild from Image to Byte array using ImageConverter in c#

Tags: c#, image, conventions

I am converting my Image from picturebox to byte array as

```
   public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
    {
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
    }
```

and then conveting the byte array to image as

```
  public static Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] imageData)
    {
        try
        {
            Image image;
            using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                inStream.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
                image = Bitmap.FromStream(inStream);
            }
            return image;
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }
```

Here for the first time before I save the data, I am uploading the file from local system to the picture box as

```
       openFileDialog1.Filter = "JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {

            Image pic = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            pboxPhoto.Image = pic;
        }
```

It is working 100% for the 1st time I am saving the data to database. When I retrive the data I am converting the data from retrived byte array to Image and attaching to picturebox.Everything is ok until now. now I want to update all the records, this time the ImagetoByte arrat method is throwing an exception as

```
A generic error occurred in GDI+.
```

So my problem is **when I upload the image from local system is converting but when I convert the byte array to Image and then try to convert the image to byte array, the method throwing above exception**. Thank you..

Comment: How are you getting the image from the picture box?

Comment: I am calling the method as  byte[] img = ImageToByte(pboxPhoto.Image);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you close the underlying stream of the bitmap in `byteArrayToImage` when you dispose the `MemoryStream`.

You must not do this with [`Bitmap.FromStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx) as the remarks of the its documentation say

> You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.

[`Image.FromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx) behaves similarly, it keeps the file locked until the image is disposed.